# Spark executors created without root permission in spark kubernetes 3.0.1

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes

I have recently shifted to Spark 3.0.1 with kubernetes as a resource manager. I am facing an issue that spark executors are created without root permission that's why when i am reading any file then it is showing me "File not found(Permission Denied)".

This is working fine if i downgrade to spark 2.4.4 but not with spark 3.0.1 kubernetes.

Please help me with this issue.